# How to Handle JSON with escaped Unicode characters using python json module?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, unicode

EDIT: The error doesn't appear in Prompt, but in the following Google App Engine environment.
[image: Code execution environment]
I have following json

```
>>>dat = r"""{"name":"Something", "data":"For youth \n\nBe a hero! Donate blood!\n\u091c\u092f \u0939\u093f\u0902\u0926! \u0935\u0928\u094d\u0926\u0947 \u092e\u093e\u0924\u0930\u092e\u094d"}"""
```

It contains unicode escaped characters.
I want to parse this. So I did

```
>>>jsDat = json.loads(js)
```

Then following works

```
>>>name = jsDat.get('name')
>>>name = name.encode('ascii') #This is because json module handles in unicode
>>>print name
Something
```

But trying for the field with unicode data, that is "data", an error is displayed

```
>>>data = jsDat.get('data')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 366-367: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How should I parse the data?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem at all, are you sure you did this on a python prompt?

Comment: You can't just post any random code with the error. You must post the *exact* code that generated the error.

Comment: Is Not on the prompt but in a file. I have just seen you are right. On prompt there is no error. I did it in a Google App Engine Python environment.

Comment: @Sravan - I think you're missing a line - the UnicodeEncodeError is probably the result of `data = data.encode('ascii')`, right?

Comment: I have put up a screen-shot in the question producing the error

Comment: I haven't used GAE, but it looks like it can't handle non-ASCII characters on the terminal - see my answer below for a workaround.

Comment: in fact the problem is not when you do jsDat.get('data') but when you do print data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't encode unicode to ASCII if the characters exceed the ASCII character set.  If you want to force the conversion, and lose data, you can do this:

```
data = jsDat.get('data')
data = data.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

See the doc for [str.encode](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) for more details about the ignore.

As an aside, I'm not sure why you're trying to encode to ASCII - the JSON module seems to handle that raw string just fine?

Comment: Ok, it worked. I am encoding it back into ascii, because python json module handles it in unicode. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from your 'print' line, and only because you're trying to print to a 'terminal' that doesn't understand the encoding. Doing anything else with the JSON object shouldn't produce errors.